# JS Bookmarklet -- Script won't run on some sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I'm creating a bookmarklet that works great on some sites, but not at all on others. When it fails, the script is still added to the bottom... but only part of the javascript runs.

I'm assuming there are javascript conflicts... thoughts? I've noticed that I works least on sites that already have jQuery.

The code is below. Thanks!

```
if (!($ = window.jQuery)) {
    alert('no jquery! its being added');
    script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
    script.onload=runEverything;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
} else {
    alert('jquery exists!');
    runEverything();
}
```

Comment: What does "won't run" mean? Any errors? And why are you assigning `window.jQuery` to `$` inside your `if`?

Comment: It means that `runEverything()` won't fire. The `if` is detecting whether the `$` is already assigned to something (jQuery, Prototype, etc).

Comment: It's not detecting, it's assigning `window.jQuery` to `$`. You have to use `==` for checking, not `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
if (!($ == window.jQuery)) {
    alert('no jquery! its being added');
    script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
    script.onload=runEverything;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
} else {
    alert('jquery exists!');
    runEverything();
}
```

Althought I recommend this;

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    alert('no jquery! its being added');
    script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
    script.onload=runEverything;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
} else {
    alert('jquery exists!');
    runEverything();
}
```